# Google Cloud Run - Create Services not working

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-run

I've just started using Google Cloud Run for a work project. I'm trying to use API calls to spawn services on demand. I'm able through a simple python code to list the services my project has, but now I'm trying to create a new one. I got some 400 errors for field violation but when solved now get a 404 not found with no further explanation.

My code is the following:

```
 import requests

project_id = ****
region = ****
service_id = ****
# Set the URL for the Cloud Run service endpoint
url = f"https://run.googleapis.com/v2/projects/{project_id}/locations/{region}/services/{service_id}"


access_token = ****
# Set the Google Cloud credentials (authentication)
headers = {
    "Authorization": f"Bearer {access_token}",
    "Content-Type": "application/json" 
}

body = {
    "name": "",
    "description": "test",
    "generation": "1",
    "labels": {
        "cloud.googleapis.com/location": "us-central1"
      },
    "template": {
    "containers": {
        "image": f"gcr.io/{project_id}/gcr.io/****/test1:v01"
    }
  }
}



# Make the API call to get details about the Cloud Run service
response = requests.post(url, headers=headers,json=body)

# Check if the request was successful
if response.status_code == 200:
    # Parse and print the response JSON
    service_details = response.json()
    print("Service Details:")
    print(service_details)
else:
    print(f"Error: {response.status_code} - {response.text}")
```

My GET code works like a charm but I'm having troubles with POST. The description of the service to create is barely detailed because for now I just need it to work, I believe that's not what is braking the code.

The response is:
`Error: 404 - <!DOCTYPE html>`
as I mentioned earlier.

I'm having such a bad time finding clear documentation or tutorials so please help me.

I tried switching around parameters and values. I expect someone that does this kind of implementation can help or guide me.

Comment: I recommend using the CLI `gcloud` and adding the command arg `--log-http` to see how Google executes commands. This will save you heaps of time trying to figure out URLs, query params, and request bodies. Also, see Ben's answer for the 404 error.

Answer (score 1):

You have the wrong URL

So first, I'd recommend you use the [client library](https://cloud.google.com/python/docs/reference/run/latest) instead of building the request manually if you can. But if you do want to craft it by hand, the documentation is [here](https://cloud.google.com/run/docs/reference/rest/v2/projects.locations.services/create). You'll need to send a POST to [https://run.googleapis.com/v2/projects/{project_id}/locations/{region}/services](https://run.googleapis.com/v2/projects/%7Bproject_id%7D/locations/%7Bregion%7D/services) (note the service ID isn't included here) with the serviceId as a query param and the body being the Service resource.

Comment: Oh yeaaah, it’s a query param! My bad. I’ll try later and let you know. I tried with the client library but it would take me longer to figure out how to make it work and in the end I need a url query because it will need to be embedded on a web page. 
Thank you so much!